# Function not returning empty string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a function for a nodejs application that is intended to display a license badge based on which one is chosen from a list and to return an empty string when the 'none' option is selected. The badges are displayed as expected for every option, but when 'none' selected, the badge is still displayed as 'none'.

```
function renderLicenseBadge(license) {
  if (license.licence !== 'none') {
    return (`[![License: ${license.license}](https://img.shields.io/badge/license-${license.license}-blue.svg)](#license)`);
  } else {
    return '';
  }
};
```

Comment: What are the possible values of license? You should check what the value of `license.license` is. Could it be `null`?

Comment: `license` vs. `licence` typo?

Comment: Yep, it was definitely a typo. I finally saw after hours of being stuck and immediately added a spell check extension to my vs code. Thank you 